# Unable to send HTTP request to the Schema registry End Point when my producer app is deployed in test environment

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

The exception is  Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://kafkatestserver:8081/subjects/topicname/versions

The properties are below:

```
schemaRegistryEndPoint = http://kafkatestserver:8081
spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType = application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = vs-kafkabroker-9093-testenv-datacenter.organizationname.com:9093
```

When i am trying to produce a record to the kafka cluster to the same destination when running my producer app through a local host, everything works fine. The problem comes when i deploy it on a test server and try sending a message this exception occurs.

Any inputs will be of help.

Below is the stacktrace

```
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:178) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:235) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:326) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:318) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:313) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:119) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:156) [kafka-schema-registry-client-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:79) [kafka-avro-serializer-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53) [kafka-avro-serializer-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:841) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar!/:?]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:433) [spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:372) [spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:209) [spring-kafka-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:382) [spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) [spring-integration-core-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.1.
```

Comment: Well, sounds like a connection/firewall problem. Can you SSH to this "test server" and curl the registry?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my Question. Yes it was a firewall/Port Issue. The Ports were blocked for any incoming requests from pre prod environments. Figured this out after talking to our security engineering folks